# chronyd not responding to some hosts

Tags: ntp, chrony

I have a vanilla install of CentOS 8 ad am using it as an NTP server with Chronyd. It is silently refusing to answer a host on its own network, but it *will* answer another host I have tested off network:

[image]

On the left, a host on its own network. Asking it repeatedly for response and it sending nothing. On the right, a host off network that syncs without problem. I have not configured any sort of ACL nor set any settings on chronyd other than to set an upstream NTP server.

I just don't have any idea why it would respond to one but not the other.

Comment: that upstream NTP server: is it configured to allow queries from the host on the left?

Comment: Unless there is some weird default filtering, I haven't allowed or not allowed any specific servers

Answer (score 0):

There was a time that this host had been a 192.168.1.0/24 address. Evidently chronyd is set to only allow its local subnet by default (for reasons) and that does not update when you change IP.

Go check the `allow` statement in your NTP server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my implementation. There's a crucial detail in the [FAQ](https://chrony.tuxfamily.org/faq.html) "You need to add an allow directive to the chrony.conf file in order for chronyd to open the server NTP port and respond to client requests."

```
echo "allow" >> /etc/chrony/chrony.conf
```

and restarting `chronyd` did the trick for me.